# l.append[i], object is not subscriptable?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, append

When I do:

```
l = []
for i in range(10):
    if i%3 == 0 or i%5 == 0:
        l.append[i]
print sum(l)
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PE1.py", line 4, in <module>
    l.append[i]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

Is there really no way append all the i's that pass the condition?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`append` is a method, you use function call syntax.

```
l.append(i)
```

Also, more elegant approach in cases like this is to use list comprehension:

```
l = [i for i in range(10) if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0]
```

Answer (score 11):

`l.append[i]`

Wrong parenthesis. You should use:

`l.append(i)`